# JPA @NamedQuery select by @OneToMany object type

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, jql

Suppose we have the following situation: A parent has a list of children whilst each children is either of type "number" or "alphabet" and I want to select the parents which either

- Have one or more "number" children whose "number" is equal to 42
- Have no "number" children at all (but may have "alphabet" children)

I have the following minimal example and I have already solved the first case but no idea about the second one because I assume that I would have to filter by object type and I am not sure whether this is feasible or not via SQL only (I would like not to filter in Java to reduce the amount of entities in question as early as possible).

## Parent.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "findWithNumberChildrenContainingNumber42", query = "SELECT nc.parent from NumberChild nc WHERE nc.number = 42"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "findWithoutNumberChildren", query = "?")
})
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Child> children;

    // ...
}
```

## Child.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
abstract class Child implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;

    // ...
}
```

## NumberChild.java

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class NumberChild extends Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Integer number;

    // ...  
}
```

## AlphabetChild.java

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class AlphabetChild extends Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String alphabet;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Normally I only deal with native queries, but doesn't this work in JPQL `SELECT p FROM Parent p WHERE p.id NOT IN (SELECT nc.parent.id from NumberChild nc)`.

Comment: @coladict If you rewrite this as an "answer", I would accept it!

Comment: Well it might not be a good answer, because at least in Hibernate that subquery doesn't optimize to `select parent_id from number_child`, but it actually joins to the NumberChild table with Parent by that id, and selects it from the Parent table. The real produced query is needlessly inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the previous query was more complicated than necessary, so here's one I just tested.

```
SELECT p FROM Parent p WHERE p NOT IN (SELECT nc.parent FROM NumberChild nc)
```

Well, in my test the names were different, but Hibernate's logs show it did generate a more efficient query.